# Iterate in the SQL Query

Tags: sql

Table: biller

```
bill_id  |  amount
---------|---------
1        | 100
1        | 200
1        | 300
2        | 100
2        | 500
2        | 650
```

Output I want is: output is a table with sum of all the amounts with same bill_id.

```
bill_id  |  total
---------|---------
1        | 600
2        | 1250
```

**Please suggest SQL Query.** and an explanation please.

Comment: select  bill_id, sum(amount) total from <tbl_name>  group by bill_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

‘Select sum(amount) as total from biller group by bill id’. 
Please read group by operation

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT bill_id, SUM(amount) AS TOTAL
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY 1
```

For each value of "id", you are asking SQL to sum up all the "amounts" and give you a total.

When you use an aggregate function, you need to group these values by something. You need to group by your ID (aka column '1' like I have done above).